# Simple Configurable Products - add text before price of simple product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, extensions, simple-product

I am using the Simple Configurable Products extension.

Right now there is text before a configurable product price that reads "starts at"

How can I add text to precede the price of a simple product?

Can I limit that text to simple products in certain categories only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display of a product is basically independent from the Simple Configurable Products extension.

If you want to limit the text that displays, you have a couple of approaches you can take:

Firstly you can provide a name that is what you want to use, or in your theme's template file(s) based on where you wish to display the information, you can do checks prior to outputting.

Example:

`$category = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
if($category->getName() == 'something) { echo $category->getName() . " " .  $_product->getName(); } else { echo $_product->getName(); }`

You will want to verify you have a category here of course, and any other checks to ensure you display only what you need to.

I suggest you enable the Template Hints in the admin panel to help you identify which template files parts of the site are being loaded from.

Hope that helps.